# Enable Remote Access to SQL Server 2008 R2 (no SSMS)

Tags: sql-server-2008, remote-access

My VPS has limited space, and was trying a few times to install SQL Server 2008 R2 with SSMS; but installation has failed due to hard drive free space (there only 2.5 GB). Now my plan is to install only SQL Server 2008 R2. It can be administered remotely, but on every link [found](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) about how to enable remote access there step that involves local SSMS:

- check "Allow remote connections to this server"

  My question is can it be done without SSMS installed?

Comment: What version? Express is the only version that has remote connections off by default, Standard, Dev and Enterprise allow them by default.

Comment: Mine is SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using T-SQL our sister (mother?) site already has the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975780/sql-server-enable-remote-connections-without-ssms

Simply log in the sql command line and issue:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'remote access', N'1'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

Comment: Damn, beat me by a couple of mouse clicks!